# No visible interface for UITableViewController declares the selector ReloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a `UITableViewController` as my primary ViewController in an app. My goal is to override the `reloadData` method.

Both the delegate and datasource of the tableview were set in the Storyboard automatically:[image]

However, when I call the super method of the class in the override, I get the error seen in the title of this question.

my code is very very simple:

```
- (void)reloadData {
    [super reloadData];
}
```

Furthermore, when I call `reloadData` without the override in other parts of my app, it does not seem to trigger `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"theThingImLookingFor"]) {
        [self.tableView reloadData]; //no error thrown, but no tableReloading either
    }
}
```

How do I get this to work? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here...

Comment: `reloadData` is a method on `UITableView` not on `UITableViewController` explains why `[super reloadData];` generates an error.  As for the other, are you sure `parser:didEndElement...` is getting called with an appropriate element name?

Comment: That makes so much more sense... Good to know for the first thing. For the latter, I am positive that reloaddata is being called I have a break point that confirms it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableViewController` does not define a `reloadData` method. That's a `UITableView` method. If you've defined one, it won't get called unless you call it yourself. I suggest putting a breakpoint on your `reloadData` method and seeing from where it's being called.

If you yourself call your reloadData method it won't do anything. You need to call your tableView's reloadData method.

You could certainly implement a reloadData method in your `UITableViewController` that in turn calls the table view's reloadData method:

```
- (void)reloadData {
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```